# foundation-sites 6.3.1: Function rem-calc has no parameter named $base

Tags: zurb-foundation

I'm facing an issue after the installation of foundation-sites 6.3.1 via NPM.

```
messageFormatted: node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/util/_unit.scss
Error: Function rem-calc has no parameter named $base
    on line 61 of node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/util/_unit.scss
    $value: rem-calc($value, $base: 16px);
-----------------------------^

messageOriginal: Function rem-calc has no parameter named $base
relativePath: node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/util/_unit.scss
```

I removed everything to install again. I don't understand... would you have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I too came across this today, after much fiddling about it looks like when you last upgraded Foundation they broke it...

Change

```
@function rem-calc($values, $base-value: $rem-base) {
  $max: length($values);

  @if $max == 1 { @return convert-to-rem(nth($values, 1), $base-value); }

  $remValues: ();
  @for $i from 1 through $max {
    $remValues: append($remValues, convert-to-rem(nth($values, $i), $base-value));
  }
  @return $remValues;
}
```

too

```
@function rem-calc($values, $base: $rem-base) {
  $max: length($values);

  @if $max == 1 { @return convert-to-rem(nth($values, 1), $base); }

  $remValues: ();
  @for $i from 1 through $max {
    $remValues: append($remValues, convert-to-rem(nth($values, $i), $base));
  }
  @return $remValues;
}
```

in `foundation/scss/foundation/_function.scss`

Why or when they changed it I have no idea.